# how to save information, using laravel in a relationship ManytoMany

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel and I want to save the information in a table of many to many. Here is the view of the page, and how the table is made.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArWja.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/okk4A.png

Comment: Please provide some example codes what you've tried so far. Also please read more on how to provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, [why you should not post images of code/error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0):

For performing actions on many to many relationships, Laravel provides various helper methods such as attach, detach, sync and more.

For example- if you want to add new course (with score of 50) to a user, you can do something like this:

```
$user->courses()->attach($courseId, ['score' => 50])
```

More information: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships